# Laravel `delete()` affecting other timestamp columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, soft-delete

I am using Laravel soft deletes in order to "delete" a record. But something odd is taking place,  the `delete()` command used to soft delete the record is apparently affecting other time stamp rows in my table when it should not, unless I've missed something critical.

**My Model** (Only relevant part included, Namespaces are all properly included):

```
use SoftDeletes;
protected $fillable = [ 'card_id', 'expiry_date' ]; // where expiry_date is the timestamp row being affected.
protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
```

**My Controller**:

```
public function destroy(IdCardFormRequest $request, $id)
{
    $idCard = IdCard::find($id);
    if(isset($idCard )){

        $operationStatus = $idCard ->delete();

        if($operationStatus) {
            $request->session()->flash('status', 'success');
            $request->session()->flash('message', 'Id card deleted successfully');
            return redirect()->route('admin.id-card.index');
        }
    }
}
```

**The Problem** 
When i initiate the deletion process using the appropriate route the MySql data row is soft deleted properly, but the other time stamp based row i.e. `expiry_date` gets updated to the current time stamp. I've read the entire documentation related to soft deleting in Laravel and it doesn't mention that the other time stamp columns will be affected.

[The documentation I've read](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#soft-deleting)

---

**Edit:**
 Well I've solved it using `dateTime()` instead of `timestamp()`. Im still not sure that this is a proper solution to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the database you're using, datetime and timestamp column types may do different things.

In MariaDB/MySQL for example, [datetime](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/datetime/) is just a column type that holds the date and time in a specific format.

The [timestamp](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/timestamp/) column type also holds the date and time, but will automatically update when the record is added/updated unless explicitly overridden.

From the MariaDB documentation:

> The timestamp field is generally used to define at which moment in time a row was added or updated and by default will automatically be assigned the current datetime when a record is inserted or updated.